# How to style a <div> to look like TextArea

Tags: css

I am displaying emails from a log file and display the body, which is sent as HTML, using @HTML.Raw. The screen displays correctly, however the style does not match input fields on the form (see picture).  I am using css to attempt to match the style of my  to make it look like a  but can't seem to make it work.  A TextArea has rounded edges, a scroll bar, and a margin.  I've tries a bunch of css options but can't seem to match the style.  Ideas?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-sm-1">
   <label class="control-label">Body</label>
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-11 TextDiv" >
   @Html.Raw(Model.Body)
</div>
```

`

[image]

Comment: as per _rounded edges, scrollbar, margin_ you have the css properties `border-radius`, `overflow: scroll`, `padding` ... but you have a different font size also and you didn't show the rest of your html including the other fields you are inspired to, nor how did you set the `.TextDiv` rule

Comment: .TextDiv {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width:90%;
    background: #e9ecef;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    left:12px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function toggleEditable() {
    var textDiv = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
    textDiv.classList.toggle("editable");
  }

  // Attach an event listener to toggle the editable class when clicked
  document.getElementById("editableDiv").addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleEditable();
  });
```

```css
.TextDiv {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 100px; 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .TextDiv.editable {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-sm-1">
     <label class="control-label">Body</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-11 TextDiv" contenteditable="true" id="editableDiv">
     @Html.Raw(Model.Body)
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the scrollbar will never kick in because there's no `height` nor `max-height`. The rounded corners are missing. The `font-family` was not addressed. The `font-size` is guessed. And those were explicit requests made (and the only ones). The `contenteditable` feature was taken for granted and yet the question was missing important information